# Unable to load external CSS in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am try to load an external css file to my current html file but with no success.
i am including images regarding the code:
[The code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9rDS.png)

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je7cf.png)

i am currently on Windows and using aptana studio 3 as ide.

Comment: You should use a relative path. What is your directory structure?

Comment: go it working. i did not add the class="..." to the element i want to style thats why no effect

Answer (score 0):

Place the CSS files in CSS folder of your project and use "css/master.css"

Comment: Actually explain why you need to do that. It's a relative path. You could explain the difference between an absolute and relative path is.

Comment: solved it i had made mistakes . i made the css but did not add the class to the element :P .Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Absolute path -location of directory from root whereas relative path is relative to the directory.Use absolute path , if the css is from another website and relative path if CDs file is in your local directory.

Comment: If issue is resolved..could you please mark it as answered :)